# HttpListener - Limit Request Length

Tags: c#, http

I'm writing a HttpListener based server which accepts binary files and uploads to S3. I want to reject big files before actually reading whole request. This is my approach:

```
var ctx = await listener.GetContextAsync();
var req = ctx.Request;

if ( req.ContentLength64 > SIZE_LIMIT )
    result = ERROR_RESPONSE;
else
{
    using ( BinaryReader r = new BinaryReader( req.InputStream ) )
    {
        bytes = r.ReadBytes( Convert.ToInt32( req.ContentLength64 ) );
        upload( bytes );
    }
}
```

So, my question is, if I check HttpListenerRequest.ContentLength64 before reading anything from the InputStream, HttpListener doesn't read the binary content, does it?

Comment: Depends on the client and the implementation of `ContentLength64`. For example using chunked transfer encoding, the length is unknown until the final chunk was received. See HTTP RFCs ("determining message body length") and HttpListener's documentation.